# adding a second variable to jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

attendance 1 is a radio button. I have 2 radio buttons on my page how do I add the second radio button to this jquery script called attendance2

```
//code before this
    }); 
             }); 
            $(document).ready(function(){        
                $("input[name=attendance1]:checked").triggerHandler('click');  
                               });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute selector to select all radio buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").triggerHandler('click');  
});
```

If you don't care if they are selected or not:

```
$("input[type=radio]").triggerHandler('click');
```

Comment: the type of all my radio are 'checkbox' and i inserted your code but its not working

Comment: corection it does work just for the first radio button group (attendance1)

Comment: @Jacob. So they are not exist in the page... check it with `$("input[type=radio]").each(function(){alert ($(this).attr('name'));});`

Comment: each radio button is type=radio :s

Comment: @Jacob. Sorry didn't understand what you meant. Anyway did it alert you `attendance2` ???

Comment: @Jacob. Enough of the guessing game! show your full code, and a JSFiddle is even better